# Zooming in on a map with elements in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a zoomable map of the world with a single point on it (in reality there are multiple points from a separate resource but I have simplified it). [The block is here.](http://bl.ocks.org/whatsthebeef/6518269)

When I try and zoom in it jumps to a certain scale and then usually doesn't allow any more zooming movements. I have experimented with various different values for the `transition`, `scale` and `scaleExtent` taken from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340) and [this one](http://wahrendorf.de/circlemapping/world_question.html) (with the latter being very close to what I want overall) but nothing has worked. It seems to get quite close to the actual size at `height/6` for minimum zoom but still behaves badly.

I suspect the main problem is with `scaleExtent`. I actually want the minimum zoom to be the size of the map and so it isn't possible to pan around unless zoomed in.

The other problem is, as you can see in the bl.ock that the circle disappears when you zoom. I want the circle to maintain position and size (so it **doesn't** get bigger when I zoom).

Can any one help with

- The zoom problem on the map, so the map minimum zoom is the actual size map and I can zoom in to about 6x that
- Preventing the map from panning unless zoomed in
- Maintaining the size and position of the circle on the map

Comment: You should consider using [the zoom behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior) for this. You can implement all of your constraints on top of it.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am using the zoom behaviour `d3.behavior.zoom()`. Early, I was using a zoom on the main group which was simpler and worked well however I needed to be able to manipulate the actual shapes and I couldn't work out a way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put an example of what I *think* you're after on [this bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/6522279) which is based on the first example you pointed to.  It looks as though this line `.scaleExtent([height, height*6])` is limiting the scale (well that the purpose of it) to something that was incompatible with your expectations and the initial scale you set, so when you zoom in past a certain level (in this case *height*) you get stick between *height* and *height* * *6*.

If you set your minimum zoom and your initial zoom I think you'll get around some of your issues.

The issue with the dots was that they weren't referenced in the redraw function, so when you zoomed d3 / the browser didn't know what to do with them.  In my example I've put the following snippet in to address this:

```
g.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return projection(d)[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function (d,i) { return projection(d)[1]; })
    .attr("r", "10px")
    .style("fill", "red");
```